# Where would I put the .title function in order for the final output to have the words beginning with a capital letter?

Tags: python, input

I know this is probably a simple problem but as a beginner I thought I would ask. I have created a simple Python script to run through terminal where, after being asked three questions, the user will be given an output with it all in. I would like to add to this by capitalising all words answered and I know I could use the .title function but im not sure where to put it. any help would be much appreciated.

```
#ask user for age
name = input('What is your name?: ')
print(name)
#ask user age
age = input('How old are you?: ')
print(age)
#ask user for city
city = input('What city were you born in?: ')
print(city)
#ask user what they enjoy
hobby = input('What do you enjoy doing in your spare time?: ')
print(hobby)
#create output text
string = 'Your name is {} and you are {} years old. you were born in      {} and you enjoy {}'
output = string.format(name, age, city, hobby)

#print output to screen
print(output)
```

Comment: There are only a couple of places - why not simply try it out? Do you _need_ a professional guidance on this? Does something explode if you fail?

Comment: Patrick beat me to it. The computer will not explode if you put it in the wrong place. You'll learn far more from trying things out than straight answers

Comment: name.title()  in you string.format(...)

Comment: This question will probably being read by 50 to 150 ppl in the next hour .. thats about 2.5 hours of lifetime spent by somebody Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will put it in this line:

```
output = string.format(name.title(), age.title(), city.title(), hobby.title())
```

This is pretty straight forward since this is what you add to the final output.

You could also add it straight after asking for input like this:

```
my_name = input('Enter your name:').title()
```